# Why doesnt this xpath work when a namespace is put into the element?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EchoWithPostResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <EchoWithPostResult>
        Hello World
    </EchoWithPostResult>
</EchoWithPostResponse>
```

When I use the xpath:

> /EchoWithPostResponse/EchoWithPostResult

Nothing gets selected. However when I take out the namespace it works (the inner node is selected s), so when I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EchoWithPostResponse>
  <EchoWithPostResult>
    <add key="AuthDllPath" value="" />
  </EchoWithPostResult>
</EchoWithPostResponse>
```

How do I account for the namespace, I cant really have them taken out unfortunately.

Comment: You *shouldn't* have them taken out! You know how dentists in the 1950s used to take out all your teeth when you had a cavity? That solved the problem, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/a:EchoWithPostResponse/a:EchoWithPostResult
```

Comment: How does that help, without declaring the `a` namespace prefix?

Comment: Read comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438110/why-doesnt-this-xpath-work-when-a-namespace-is-put-into-the-element/6438126#6438126

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare and use the namespace.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate? I cant change the source xml its a webservice. How do I do this with the xpath?

Comment: How are you invoking the XPath expression?

Comment: The "Namespace Reference" table on the right contains the namespace identifiers you should use.

Comment: Are you saying that I cant use this tool if I use a namespace? The samespace comes up but it still wont work :-(, is this tool useless when namespaces are involved?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to look at the "Namespace Reference" table on the right for the namespace identifiers you should use.

Comment: Since the XML document is using the default namespace (without prefix), the prefix 'a' is assigned to it by the tool. Try this: `/a:EchoWithPostResponse/a:EchoWithPostResult`. Remember these pointers: XPath requires namespace information; there's no such thing as a default namespace in XPath, it requires prefixes. XPath originated in the context of XSLT, taking it out of that context requires a little effort.

Comment: thanks I have awarded the answer to Kirilli as they provided it but I respect your explanation thankyou!